# api get request fails, but post, put, delete work

Tags: ios, api, express, react-native, axios

Environment and Settings:

- react-native 0.57
- expressjs for server
- using axios for api request
- set timeout 10000ms
- the request is a json data with username and small other infos
- http request (not https)

---

I'm developing a small react native project and now having a trouble with "api GET request".

It's all perfect for POST, PUT, DELETE actions but only the GET request returns timeout error with "BadRequestError: request denied" server log.

The same code on android works just fine, but it only happens on ios.

I've set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true and also NSExceptionDomains just in case but neither of them solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got a solution.

It was because of an empty object on body when sending 'GET' request. 
checking if it is empty and making it undefined solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Latest iOS sdk enforces connection to be in **https** protocol instead of http.

you can add an exception to your domain inside info.plist file of the Xcode project.

if you want to allow everything write this inside **info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>yourdomain.com</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. Open your project in xcode.
2. Right click on **info.plist**.
3. Choose **Open As** Source code.
4. Add below code before end of `</dict>` tag.

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```